# Error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream

Tags: c++

Получаю

```
src/playlistApp.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > get_playlist(int)’:

src/playlistApp.cpp:92:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string, const openmode&)’

src/playlistApp.cpp:92:73: note: candidates are:

/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:460:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
```

в

```
std::vector<std::string> get_playlist(int day) {

std::vector<std::string> playlist;

std::ifstream playlist_file(get_path_playlist(day), ios_base::binary);

std::string str;

while (std::getline(playlist_file, str)) {

    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" \n\r") + 1);

    std::vector<std::string> temp = split(str, '.');
    std::string exe = temp[temp.size() - 1];

    if (exe == std::string("mp4") || exe == std::string("avi")) {

        int vector_size = playlist.size();

        if (vector_size > 0) {

            bool is = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {
                if (playlist[i] == str) {
                    is = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!is) {
                playlist.push_back(str);
                //std::cout << str << std::endl;
            }

        } else {
            playlist.push_back(str);
            //std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

return playlist;
}
```

далее несколько статичных функций...

```
void playlistApp::keyPressed  (int key){...}
```

и т.д.

ошибка в этой строке (см. функцию выше)

```
    std::ifstream playlist_file(get_path_playlist(day), ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: Ну очевидно же, что тут же будет задан дополнительный вопрос: что возвращает `get_path_playlist()`?

Comment: путь до файла в формате std::string  
всё решилось, помогла информация от @fori1ton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам же компилятор чёрным по белому пишет, что у `std::ifstream` нет конструктора, принимающего `std::string` и `openmode&`. Зато есть конструктор, принимающий `const char*` и `openmode&`. Посему эту строку нужно переписать так:

```
std::ifstream playlist_file(get_path_playlist(day).c_str(), ios_base::binary);
```